# Access VBA - XLS Late Binding, Variable not Found

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am trying to address some XLS reference mismatches for a few users by implementing Late Binding in my AccessDB application.  I have solved a few of the issues, but created a new one.

With Late Binding and the XLS Reference removed, I am getting a "Variable Not Defined" at the term "LookAt:=xlWhole" (see snippet, below).

Question:  Do I lose access to these variables with Late Binding?  And then, how do I work around to retain the needed functionality in a Late Binding scenario?

Snippet from the complaining module:

```
Dim appXLS As Object
Dim wbk As Object
Dim wks1, wks2, wks3, wks4, wks5 As Object
'...other unrelated declarations

'...unrelated code

'Create the Excel Application, Workbook and Worksheet

Set appXLS = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wbk = appXLS.Workbooks.Add(1)

appXLS.Visible = True
wbk.Activate

'...more unrelated code

'...first offending line:
wks1.Range("E1:E" & intRows).Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", 
LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Any suggestions to get me started, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by removing the reference to the Excel object library, you lose these constants.

Solution: Copy their definition from the Object browser into a standard module:

```
Const xlWhole = 1
Const xlByColumns = 2
```

or (less readable) use the numbers directly when calling the Excel methods.

```
LookAt:=1, _       ' xlWhole
SearchOrder:=2, _  ' xlByColumns
MatchCase:=False, _
SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

might be acceptable for you.

---

By the way and unrelated:

```
Dim wks1, wks2, wks3, wks4, wks5 As Object
```

declares wks1 ... wks4 as Variant (the default datatype), not as Object.

Comment: Success.  Thank you for the prompt response.